# After Home button pressed and pressed icon (on launcher) app restart

Tags: android, restart, android-homebutton

If install app from sd by default installer and Open button pressed will open app. After Home button pressed and click icon (on launcher) app will restart. Need kill app from memory and start by icon on launcher for normal behaviour.

Steps:
 1. Create simple app
 2. Load to sd
 3. Install and Open from installer
 4. Change any behavior
 5. Pressed Home button
 6. Pressed icon app on launcher
 7. App restarting !

If kill app from memory and run by icon on launcher will behavior is normal.
How do it resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

I solved this issue with the following code in the `onCreate()` method:

```
if (!isTaskRoot()) { 
    final Intent intent = getIntent(); 
    final String intentAction = intent.getAction(); 
    if (intent.hasCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER) && 
            intentAction != null && intentAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_MAIN)) { 
        finish(); 
    } 
}
```

Opposed to other proposed solutions, this does not require the declaration of `"android.permission.GET_TASKS"`

Answer (score 2):

Please check for the flag android:launchMode for activity in Android Manifest. Try deleting it and check.

Comment: This was exactly my problem, the launcher Activity had launchMode:singleInstance. Deleting it fixed this issue.